# Getting j.n.SocketException: Connection reset by peer when I use 1000 open connection

Tags: macos, performance-testing, gatling, web-api-testing, gatling-plugin

I am using mac to test some apis using gatling. when I test 1000 around 450 of the connections are refused and anf this is really affecting my tests.Here is what I get

```
> j.n.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
```

and here is my scenario

```
  def postNewQuery() = {
    exec(http("Post New Query")
          .post("/searches/")
            .body(ElFileBody("bodies/createQueryBody.json")).asJson
          .check(status.is(201)))
    }

   val scn = scenario("Post new games")
      .exec(postNewQuery())


  setUp(
    scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1000))
  ).protocols(httpConf)


}
```

What do you usually do in this case? do you increase any limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Connection reset by peer` is exactly what happens: your network or your system under load doesn't like having to open that many sudden (`atOnceUsers(1000)`) connections at once and kills connections abruptly while requests are flying.

Regarding your question about tuning, please read the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/operations).
However, this might not fix your issue if the bottleneck is not the local machine network stack but somewhere else.